# Convert thinkscript's AdaptiveEMA to pine script

Tags: pine-script, thinkscript

Thinkscript has a seemingly simple function to calculate an Adaptive EMA. However, it uses thinkscript's built-in CompoundValue function which is not available in Pine Script.

I'm having trouble recreating the CompoundValue function in Pine Script. It's supposedly recursive, but I see in another answer that it's really some sort of nested if statement.

The thinkscript code for AdaptiveEMA:

```
input price = close;
input length = 10;
input highLowLength = 10;

def multiplier1 = 2 / (length + 1);
def multiplier2 = AbsValue((close - Lowest(low, highLowLength)) - (Highest(high, highLowLength) - close)) / (Highest(high, highLowLength) - Lowest(low, highLowLength));
def alpha = multiplier1 * (1 + multiplier2);
def ma = CompoundValue(1, ma[1] + alpha * (price - ma[1]), Average(price, length));

plot AEMA = ma;
AEMA.SetDefaultColor(GetColor(1));
```

I am trying to make this a function so I can have two AdaptiveEMAs on one chart and call them like this:

```
plot AEMAshort = adaptiveEMA(close, 25, 25);
plot AEMAlong = adaptiveEMA(close, 50, 50);
```

One of the things that's throwing me off with CompoundValue is the first parameter is the first parameter. From thinkscript reference:

> Calculates a compound value according to following rule: if a bar
> number is greater than length then the visible data value is returned,
> otherwise the historical data value is returned. This function is used
> to initialize studies with recursion.

If the first parameter in CompoundValue in the AdapativeEMA script is 1, isn't barindex pretty much always greater than 1 except in the first minute of the day?

How can I go about breaking apart the CompoundValue function in Pine Script and using it here?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//@version=5
indicator("adaptive ema", overlay = true)

price1 = input.source(close, title = "price 1")
price2 = input.source(close, title = "price 2")

length1 = input.int(10, title = "length 1")
highLowLength1 = input.int(10, title = "highlow length 1")

length2 = input.int(20, title = "length 2")
highLowLength2 = input.int(20, title = "highlow length 2")

    
f_adaptiveEMA(_price, _length, _highLowLength) =>
    _multiplier1 = 2 / (_length + 1)
    _multiplier2 = math.abs((_price - ta.lowest(low, _highLowLength)) - (ta.highest(high, _highLowLength) - _price)) / (ta.highest(high, _highLowLength) - ta.lowest(low, _highLowLength))
    _alpha = _multiplier1 * (1 + _multiplier2)
    float _ma = na
    _ma := _price * _alpha + (1 - _alpha) * nz(_ma[1], _price)
    _ma
    
    
ma1 = f_adaptiveEMA(price1, length1, highLowLength1)
ma2 = f_adaptiveEMA(price2, length2, highLowLength2)    

plot(ma1, color = color.yellow)
plot(ma2, color = color.red)
```

Comment: This did it. Thanks so much. I was making it way harder than it needed to be.